# Problems integrating my front-end code (Netlify) and my back-end code (heroku) (CORS)

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, cors, get-request

I have been doing react apps for some time now and I want to deploy my latest project. The problem is, in this particular app, I use an API Key to make requests to The Movie Database API. After figuring out that I need to hide it in the backend with an .env file (something I have never done before), I made it work perfectly on my machine using an Express server I made. The two problems that I have start when I want to make this thing go live.

I separated my front end (https://github.com/cavini/the-movie-app) from my backend (https://github.com/cavini/the-movie-app-server). I hosted the frontend code on Netlify with zero issues, but I cannot make the hosted front end website make the GET and POST requests to the backend which is on Heroku.

I have never used heroku before and I'm not sure I fully understand how it works.

Here is the message I get when I try to see what my Heroku app looks like. [Heroku deploy error?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB1vN.png)
I went looking for answers on the logs but I do not understand what it says.
Heres what that looks like: [Heroku log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaYn7.png), [Heroku log 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTo4o.png)
My questions are, do I need a static folder to host an app on heroku? If so, how do I do that? Because on the front end, react already has a build command to do so. Also, do I need the front end files too?

That's the first part of my problem. The second part is what I think is related to CORS. When I try to make the requests from my local files to the local back end code, it works perfectly, but when I try the same to the back end hosted on Heroku, I get this message on my Chrome console.[Access-Control-Allow-Origin header error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtEUh.png).

Heres what those look like on the Network tab: [Request details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJLCi.png), [Request details 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnlPl.png)

I have absolutely NO IDEA what any of this means and/or how to fix it. Can anyone please shed a light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to host the front end on netlify and the backend on heroku, you could host both front and backend on heroku from 1 github repository, which would also resolve the issue your having with Cors.

To host both front and backend on Heroku you'll need to put both folders into 1 directory,
You'll also need to add something like this to your main express file which fetches the files from your front end files and displays it

(install path)
`npm i path`,

```
const path = require('path')
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
```

Also

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
}
);
```

Also adding the following scripts to be used by Heroku:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
```

Create a Procfile if you don't already have one, as you're creating a web application which connects to ports, you'll need a web Dyno, all you need in your Procfile is `web: npm run start`

And also remember to replace the request urls with the new Heroku link that's given.
e.g previously your requests would be fetched from "https://example.com/api", after hosting on heroku and both your front end and back end are together, you'll need to make requests to "LinkGivenByHeroku/api",

The reason your getting a "failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds" error is because Heroku isn't always able give you the port you wanted, and it chooses an open port and puts it into its ENV, so where you put something like:

```
let port = 3001 
app.listen(port)
```

Change it to:

```
let port = process.env.PORT || 3001
app.listen(port)
```

Comment: Thanks a LOT Arize, you really really helped me with your comment. This was literally the only solution I found that worked for me.

Comment: I made the main page/about page load. But only the main functionality is working. When I try to get a random movie, the response I get from the API has the "data" value as undefined. Any idea why?